# Using PCA to Reduce # Dimensions in Training Set for CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pca

**Short Version:** I'm having difficulty reducing the number of dimensions of my training data using PCA. The training data is built for a 2D CNN that classifies images of graphs into three classes.

### Purpose of Model

I'm new to Principle Components Analysis. I have a 2D Convolutional Neural Network that classifies images of graphs (36 by 36 px) into one of three classes, as such:[image]

### Improving the Model

I realized that most of the pixels are white, so the CNN is very inefficient and takes a long time to train. I became aware of dimensionality reduction techniques and tried to use the PCA. I converted one of my training images to grayscale and visualized the "eigengraph" (shown on left). I then reconstructed the original from the eigengraph (shown on right).

```
X=grayscale 

pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 36)
X_proj = pca_oliv.fit_transform(X)

print(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.imshow(np.reshape(pca_oliv.components_, (36,36)), cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image] [image]

### Problem

**But I know it can do better.** This is with *n=36* dimensions. By plotting the explained variance, I find the elbow at 3 dimensions. That means with just 3 dimensions out of 36, I can preserve 91.7% of the variance.

[image]

But if I change `pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 36)` to `pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 3)`, all goes haywire: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 108 into shape (36,36)`. Why? What am I doing wrong?

### MWE

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib

"""# Import Libraries"""

# Import Libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

"""# Load Dataset"""

import pathlib
dataset_url = "*/TrainingSet.tar.gz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin = dataset_url,
                                   fname = "TrainingSet",
                                   untar = True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

"""# Display # Images to check"""

print(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
print(image_count)

"""# Display sample image"""

pip install sklearn

import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

graphs = list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png'))
PIL.Image.open(str(graphs[6]))

"""# Define Image Dimensions & Batch Size"""

batch_size = 32
img_height = 36
img_width = 36

"""# Create Training & Validation Sets (80%, 20%)"""

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

"""# Define 3 Classes"""

class_names = ['Cubic Sinusoidal', 'Linear Sinusoidal', 'Quadratic Sinusoidal']
print(class_names)

"""# Supervised Learning (9 Samples from the Training Set)"""

!pip install skimage

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subGraphs = []

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    subGraphs.append(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

subGraphs = np.array(subGraphs)
print(subGraphs.shape)

grayscale = rgb2gray(subGraphs[1])
print(grayscale.shape)

X=grayscale 

pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 36)
X_proj = pca_oliv.fit_transform(X)

print(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.imshow(np.reshape(pca_oliv.components_, (36,36)), cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')

X_inv_proj = pca_oliv.inverse_transform(X_proj)
X_proj_img = np.reshape(X_inv_proj,(1,36,36))

plt.imshow(X_proj_img[0], cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')
```

For reference, here is my Jupyter Notebook: [**PCA+CNN**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qSM91iQ-jElizS6_7COY7OWgQGEQPGRT?usp=sharing). If anyone can help, that would be great.

Comment: share the whole traceback. Also, while using `.fit_transform` at the time of error what is the shape of the `input`.

Comment: Please 1) post the full error trace of the code that produces the error (which is not `PCA(n_components = 36)` 2) **remove** any code that comes *after* the error, as it is irrelevant to the issue. Plus, 'MWE' is not an accurate term for your code, since the data used are not public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PCA` is used to reduce number of dimensions at the same time ensuring maximum possible variation is covered by this lower dimensional representation. Now, think about that, how many dimensions you have originally. As, I have seen you have used `(36, 36)` gray-scale images. Here, each of the pixels are your original features. Again you have taken 9 images to apply `PCA` on them.

As in this case you have `number of examples` is less than `number of original features` i.e, `9 < 36*36`, hence, you will need no more than `9` principle components to cover full variance. But if your number of examples was greater than the number of features `(36*36 = 1296)` therefore you would be able to take `n_components` larger values. See here, [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and [Why are there only n−1 principal components for n data if the number of dimensions is ≥n?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123318/why-are-there-only-n-1-principal-components-for-n-data-if-the-number-of-dime)

But anyways, I am not going to the deeper details of `PCA`, instead I am describing what you need to change in your code.

```
grayscale = rgb2gray(subGraphs)
print(grayscale.shape)

grayscale = grayscale.reshape((grayscale.shape[0], grayscale.shape[1] * grayscale.shape[2]))
print(grayscale.shape)
```

As `PCA` expects the input shape to be `(number of examples, number of features)`
hence, you have to keep the the `number of examples` in the first dimension, and the second dimension will be the all pixel values (original features). If you have used color image, than you would need to include all channels' features inside this same second dimension, somewhat like:

```
color_img = color_img.reshape((color_img.shape[0], color_img.shape[1] * color_img.shape[2] * color_img.shape[3]))
print(color_img.shape)
```

Now you can apply `PCA`:

```
X=grayscale 

pca_oliv = PCA(n_components = 9)
X_proj = pca_oliv.fit_transform(X)

print(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca_oliv.explained_variance_ratio_))
```

Please note that, you won't be able to set `n_components` more than `9` as you have used only 9 images. If you see the shape of the `X_proj` you will find its shape is `(9, 9)`. The first `9` is the number of examples and second `9` is each example is represented in a lower dimensional space which space has `9` dimensions (`n_components`).

Finally, do an inverse transform to get the original dimensions back, (it is just for illustration purpose, you will train your model with `X_proj` as it is the lower dimensional representation):

```
X_inv_proj = pca_oliv.inverse_transform(X_proj)
print(X_inv_proj.shape)
for index in range(len(X_inv_proj)): # 9                    
  X_proj_img = np.reshape(X_inv_proj[index],(36,36))
  plt.imshow(X_proj_img, cmap=plt.cm.bone, interpolation='nearest')
  plt.show()
```

Again, `X_proj` contains lower dimensional representation (`9` dimensions) for your `9` examples. As, it is not an image, so you need not reshape it. You can directly use it for training your model, as if these `9` features are  representative of your original `36*36` features.

Here, please note that, the inverse transformation is not a lossless transformation always. Here, in your case we have taken `9` principle components (which is maximum possible to take in this case). So, essentially we have taken `100%` variation while getting `PCA`, so, when we apply inverse transformation, it will give us the `100%` of the variation back i.e, it will restore the original data. But if we took `n_components` to some lower value, therefore the inverse transformation would not be able to restore the original information back completely, although the shape of `X_inv_proj` won't be changed, but the information it would hold won't be the complete information of the original data.

Comment: Thank you for the help @hafiz031. I think I'm starting to understand what I did wrong. First of all, the maximum # of principal components that PCA can get is the number of examples I give? So for example, if I give 9 examples, the max. #PC = 9? And so as the # PC goes down, my reconstructions get more blurry. Why is that? Also, how can I integrate the PCA *into* my CNN? Instead of 9 examples, do I feed my **entire** training dataset into the PCA and then feed the result into my CNN?

Comment: @rb3652 No, it is not always depended on the number of examples. It is hard to describe the whole thing in a comment, so I am guiding you by providing links as references, first learn what `PCA` does from here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140579/245577

Comment: The maximum number of principal Components is the number of examples -- this is just an SPECIAL CASE. When your number of points is essentially less than (or equal to) the number of points. Why? Picture this - you have a 2 points in a 2 dimensional space, how many maximum dimensions you will ever need to describe them? The answer is only one dimension. Why? As we can think these points are on a line (the principal axis in this case) and locate the points' positions wrt. this line (i.e, the components or projection along this line (the term principal Component has come in this way).

Comment: @rb3652 ...now think these `2` points are in `3-dimensional` space. How many maximum dimensions you will need to describe them in this time? The answer is still `1`. As, no matter in how many dimensions (#dimension >= 2) these `2` points reside, we will not need anything more than one dimension to describe them. This is how this special case has come. (This explanation is taken from @amoeba's comment in this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123318/why-are-there-only-n-1-principal-components-for-n-data-if-the-number-of-dime)

Comment: Now, come to the general case, when `#points > #dimensions`, in this case you will maximum need `#dimensions` `PC`s. Why? The original dimensions has redundancy (more than one dimensions represent information which is reproducible by another one). So, we do `PCA` to remove this redundancy (no `dimension` i.e, `principal axes` now collectively represent same information as they are `not correlated` i.e, the information hold by one axis cannot by found by another). So, this make sense you will never need more `principal axes` than the original number of dimension (which has redundancy indeed)...

Comment: ...to capture same amount of information.

Comment: Thank you for all the details. Let me read it and I will come back with my questions.

Comment: For reduced `n_components` the image re constructed after inverse transform was blurry because you are loosing information when you are taking less value for `n_components` and after inverse transformation they are not coming back as they are totally lost. Also note that, reducing `n_components` not only reduces Information but also reduces noise. So, if you want to use `CNN` use `PCA` if and only if this reduction removes noise more than it removes information. So, to use `CNN` use the re constructed image after inverses transformation with lower `n_components`.

Comment: @rb3652 sometimes CNN performs worse after PCA. As, PCA doesn’t know which is noise and which is information. So, sacrificing principle components may lead to loss of valuable information. So, you can see PCA with CNN is not for dimensionality reduction, rather it is for noise reduction (no guarantee btw). So, if your purpose is to use PCA for dimensionality reduction then use those lower dimensional representations (like those 9 featurese) to train an ANN.

Comment: Your comments helped me understand why the # PC = min(# samples, # features). I have two questions, which I wrote in my new question: (1) How do I integrate the PCA *into* my CNN and (2) What are the actual **features** of my PCA? Is it the different classes of graphs? Is it a characteristic of each graph? In other words, what do the features of my PCA actually *look* like?

Comment: @rb3652 (1) I already answered in some previous comment, you can use `PCA` just as a preprocessing step. `PCA` will be used here for noise reduction. Although `PCA` does not know which is feature and which is noise, but if you take `PCA` and therefore do inverse transform selectively reducing some `PC`s (as you did and found blurry images)...if you feel that these blurry images still contain most of the information needed for classification (and noise is reduced which might create problem in classification), then use these inverse transformed data to train `CNN`, as they are just usual images.

Comment: @rb3652 but remember using `PCA` doesn't guarantee performance improvement, as sacrificing `PC`s  not only reduces noise but also reduce data, because `PCA` only cares capturing variation, and the variation in each of the original features (each of the pixels) can come from both information and noise. But I can suggest you one more thing, if you want a classifier which is both capable of reducing dimension and can also classify, you can use `LDA` (Linear Discriminant Analysis). It can reduce dimension. It is itself a classifier. See here: https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/lda-vs-pca.html

Comment: @rb3652 `PCA` is a linear transformation, that means, it generates new axes by the linear combination of older axes. Simply, the new axes are just represented as the equation of lines wrt older axis. Say, for older `2D` axes `X`, `Y`, each of the `Principal Axes` from `PCA` will be in the form of `ax + by + c = 0`, simply the equation of line. But this new axes just better aligned with the data such that we can capture most of the variations by using fewer possible lines like that. As, these new axes (features) are linear combination of older features,..many times they won't be so explanatory.

Comment: ...imagine some other example, for example you are working with `iris dataset` (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) ..say we are working only with `4` features `petal length` (pl), `petal width` (pw), `sepal length` (sl) and `sepal width` (sw). Than, you did `PCA` on that. Now each of the `principal axes` got from `PCA` are some linear combination of them. Now how do you name those dimensions? Actually most of the times we can't as they are not aligned with physical world directly, although those new dimensions help capturing variance better.

Comment: @rb3652 one more thing, `CNN` can learn non linear relationship, on the other hand `PCA` can represent only linear relationship. So, `CNN` is already more powerful than `PCA` in feature extraction. So, in most of the cases you don't need to use `PCA` before using `CNN`.